# How to replace specific data (letters or number) by another data (letters if number) in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this
where the markers are on the rows and individuals are the G1:G5

```
Marker  G1  G2   G3  G4  G5        
P39     GG  GG  AA  AA  AA  
P40     GG  AA  AA  AA  TT  
P41     AA  AA  CC  TT  AA    
P23     TT  TT  AA  AA  TT    
P35     AA  AA  AA  CC  AA
```

I would like to replace the unique calls from this data frame as

```
AA=1, TT=2, GG=3, CC=4
```

and would like to save the dataframe as CSV

does anyone have a solution for the problem
many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding what you want; is this it?

```
dt <- data.frame(Marker = c('P39', 'P40', 'P41', 'P2370', 'P350'), G1 = c('GG', 'GG', 'AA', 'TT', 'AA'),
                 G2 = c('GG', 'AA', 'AA', 'TT', 'AA'), G3 = c('AA', 'AA', 'CC', 'AA', 'AA'),
                 G4 = c('AA', 'AA', 'TT', 'AA', 'CC'), G5 = c('AA', 'TT', 'AA', 'TT', 'AA'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dt[dt == 'AA'] <- 1
dt[dt == 'TT'] <- 2
dt[dt == 'GG'] <- 3
dt[dt == 'CC'] <- 4

write.csv(dt, 'filename.csv')
```

Comment: Many thanks David_B, It is correct what you understood. My problem is that for markers I have 37000 rows and I would need a command that executes the recoding AA=1, TT=2, GG=3 and CC=4, needs to be applied to the entire set. I.e 37000 markers and 500 individuals as columns.

Answer (score 1):

This would do the work:

```
library(data.table)


dt <- setDT(dt)[ ,ifelse(dt == 'AA',1,
                         ifelse(dt == 'TT',2,
                                ifelse(dt == 'GG',3,4)))]

fwrite(dt, 'filename.csv')
```

Comment: Many thanks Rafael,   In MY data I have 37000 rows (markers) for 500 individuals(columns). I tried your code by loading the package data.table and got following error x1 <- setDT(x)[ ,ifelse(dt == 'AA',1, ifelse(dt == 'TT',2, ifelse(dt == 'GG',3, ifelse(dt == 'CC', 4))))]
Error in dt == "AA" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: @Ray, the code you've tried is different from the one I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Rafael, Ihave tried to code and the since I want the  CC codes to be replaced by 4 would your modifed code look like below?

Comment: dt <- setDT(dt)[ ,ifelse(dt == 'AA',1, ifelse(dt == 'TT',2, ifelse(dt == 'GG',3, ifelse(dt == 'CC', 4))))]  please let me know, if this would be correct thanks